# Upload file without using web control

Tags: php, html, asp.net, activex

I am writing a fingerprint web application. I will read the fingerprint from user using ActiveX controls.

After that, I will get the image in the webpage. I found that the examples I found in the web requires users to click an upload image button and choose image from it.
Like the example below:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Some tells me that I need to use ftp to upload the file.
Can I have another choice? The best method is that I can use Http to upload.

Answer (score 1):

You could send a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to the server using AJAX

[Convert Data URI to File then append to FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata)

However if you are using ActiveX, why not have the ActiveX send the data to the server from within the ActiveX?